# ODBC php Excel Encoding Issues

Tags: php, excel, encoding, utf-8, odbc

I'm making an ODBC connection with php to an Excel file. However when I encounter characters like "~", "^", "´" they appear messed up as this:

Mês -> M?s

Formação -> Forma??o

I'm doing the following utf-8 treatment just to get the column names:

```
$con = odbc_connect($odbcName, $dbUser, $dbPassword)
or die('failed');

//the Set NAMES utf8 doesn't work with excel.
//$try = odbc_exec($con, "SET NAMES utf8");

$rs = odbc_exec($con, utf8_encode($dbQuery))
or die('Erro no sql');
$intNumField = odbc_num_fields($rs);

for($i=1; $i<=$intNumField;$i++){
    $columns[] = utf8_decode(odbc_field_name($rs,$i));
}
```

The file itself was saved with the Web Options -> Encoding -> Unicode (UTF-8).

Is there anything else I should be doing in PHP?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase someone stumbles the same problem as I had, I solved it the following way:

1. In the excel file change the Encoding to Western European (Windows-1252 to UTF-8);
2. In PHP convert from Windows-1252 to UTF-8 -> $value = iconv("Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $auxVar);
3. Value has the correct encoding.

For some reason the encoding of UTF-8 in Excel wasn't being handled correctly.